# Iterate for loop AFTER asynchronous callback inside has been invoked

Tags: javascript

```
for (b; b < stops.length; b += 1) {
    (function (b, c, stops, stopMarkers, map) {
        var matchFound = false;

        for (c; c < stopMarkers.length; c += 1) {
            if (stopMarkers[c].code === stops[b].atcocode) {
                // Already on the map
                matchFound = true;
            }
        }

        // If the stop isn't already on the map
        if (!matchFound) {
            map.addMarker({
                icon: icons.busStop,
                position: new plugin.google.maps.LatLng(stops[b].latitude, stops[b].longitude)
            }, function (marker) {
                alert("I SHOULD FIRE BEFORE LOOP HAS FINISHED!");
                marker.code = stops[b].atcocode;
                stopMarkers.push(marker);
            });
        }
    })(b, c, stops, stopMarkers, map);
}

alert("I SHOULD FIRE AFTER LOOP HAS FINISHED");
```

Currently the order of the above two alerts if `stops.length` is equal to one is the alert outside of the for loop followed by the one inside of the asynchronous function.

How can I change this so that the for loop only moves onto the next iteration once the `map.addMarker` callback has fired? I have looked at some other questions with similar issues and they talk about providing closure to the for loop. I tried this but have had no success.

Comment: Use a recursive function instead

Comment: @adeneo Could you provide an example in an answer?

Answer (score 0):

asynchrnous programming is ment to be non blocking, meaning not pausing the execution while waiting for a result. so you cant pause for loop until the function is done. you could do something like

```
function recursive(b, c, stops, stopMarkers, map,callback) {
        if(b==stopMarkers.length){
             return true;
             callback.call(this);
        }
        var matchFound = false;

    for (c; c < stopMarkers.length; c += 1) {
        if (stopMarkers[c].code === stops[b].atcocode) {
            // Already on the map
            matchFound = true;
        }
    }

    // If the stop isn't already on the map
    if (!matchFound) {
        map.addMarker({
            icon: icons.busStop,
            position: new plugin.google.maps.LatLng(stops[b].latitude, stops[b].longitude)
        }, function (marker) {
            alert("I SHOULD FIRE BEFORE LOOP HAS FINISHED!");
            marker.code = stops[b].atcocode;
            stopMarkers.push(marker);
            recursive(b+1, c, stops, stopMarkers, map,callback);
        });
    }
    else{
          recursive(b, c, stops, stopMarkers, map,callback)
    }
}
```

recursive(0, c, stops, stopMarkers, map,function(){})